# What is the equivalent wrap_content in jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery-ui, web-applications, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a web app for android using jquery_mobile.

Is there any equivalent way to 'layout_width:wrap_content'?

I want to set width for a label according to device width?

Any other options will also be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this through a combination of viewports and CSS.

You are most likely already using a viewport similar to the one below, since you use jQuery Mobile:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

If you then set the width of your label to 100% it should have the width of the screen, assuming it is the outmost element. Otherwise it will have the width of its parent-element.

If it still has the wrong size try to define the width of each parent-element in the dom tree down to your label.